# Managing Subversion installs on OS X

Tags: macos, svn, homebrew

I'm fairly new to OS X. I've updated SVN on my Mac using Homebrew.  I now have a copy of `svn` in `/usr/bin` (v1.7.10) and a copy in `/usr/local/bin` (v1.8.5). This copy is a symlink to `../Cellar/subversion...`.

On the commandline `which svn` gives me `/usr/bin/svn` – the older one.

My `$PATH` is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`. `/usr/bin` is before `/usr/local/bin` which explains why the older version of SVN is used.

What is the recommended way to fix this? Should I delete the `svn` files from `/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should never modify or delete the system files in `/usr/bin`. Some scripts may rely on `/usr/bin/svn`.

Instead, **modify your path to put `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`**. Put the following into your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: I'm left with two different versions of svn installed.  Do folks just ignore this? Ought I to point the /usr/bin svn files to the newer ones in /Cellar/subversion?

Comment: @GlennH Yeah, there's no problem leaving two. Don't mess with /usr/bin — it might cause more harm than good.

Comment: I'd use ```export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH``` instead of completely rewriting the PATH-Variable as it leaves a previously altered PATH intact